# Hibernate query on group by

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hql

How can I convert this postgreSql query into hibernate query:

```
select sum(amount), cat_id, 
       date_trunc('month', createOn) as month,
       date_trunc('year', createOn) as year 
from item 
where owner_id = 1 
group by cat_id , month, year;
```

I have Item class as :

```
@Column(name="AMOUNT")
private BigDecimal amount;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
private Customer owner;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="CAT_ID")
private Category category;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="CREATEON")
private Date createOn;
```

I have try to convert it to:

```
StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer()
        .append("Select sum(amount), category, month(createOn) as mon, year(createOn) as year")
        .append(" from Item")
        .append(" where owner=:owner")
        .append(" group by category, mon, year");

    Query query = getQuery(hql.toString())
                    .setParameter("owner", owner);   

    List<Object[]> resultList = query.list();
    List<BundleHolder> bundleHolderList = new ArrayList<BundleHolder>();

    for(Object[] result : resultList) {
        BundleHolder instance = BundleHolder.getInstance();
        instance.setAmount((BigDecimal) result[0]);
        instance.setCategory((Category) result[1]);
        instance.setMonth((int) result[2]);
        instance.setYear((int) result[3]);

        bundleHolderList.add(instance);
    }
```

When I run the query, I got the error as:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column "category" does not exist
```

I try to switch category to cat_id or owner to owner_id (set the parameter to owner.getId()) around, but it doesn't help as well.

Comment: Use an alias like `Select sum(item.amount), item.category, month(item.createOn) as mon, year(item.createOn) as year from Item item where item.owner=:owner group by item.category, mon, year`. (Later on, drop `FetchType.EAGER` and use other schemes like fetch joins).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried you query but it complained that I need to have item.category.id in group by. So I have fixed it by changing item.category -> item.category.id in Select and Group by. The result is fascinated. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need o change `category` to `category.id`:

```
StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer()
        .append("Select sum(amount), category.id, month(createOn) as mon, year(createOn) as year")
        .append(" from Item")
        .append(" where owner=:owner")
        .append(" group by category.id, mon, year");
```